# Programmatically accessing structure of tables in the database

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4

How can I programatically access (just access) the structure of the tables in my database. If I have a table Employee with attributes Id, Name, SSN etc. then I want to access Id, Name and SSN in code behind files of my Web Forms. I know LINQ and Entity Framework will be involved but I cannot figure out how to do this. I am using ASP.NET 4.

I dont want rows stored in the tables. I just want to know what is the structure of the table i.e. what are the columns. I want to add more columns in the tables in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do that on tables or entities ? On entities, just enumerate the properties on your data objects. On database, use the `information_schema` or something more specific provided by your database

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question? Do you want to select data from DB or do you want to read information about table structure from mapping metadata?

Comment: I want to read information about the table structure

Comment: Lets say i want to print the structure of the table. How could I do so generically and not by hardcoding it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use entity framework then, I would use normal ADO.NET to load a DataTable with a kind of SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.TableName WITH (NOLOCK) ( if you are in SQL Server scenario ), then the table contains the columns, looping on the table columns you see their type and name and that's the table schema/structure you are looking for.

You can also manipulate the tables and add columns; not in this exact way I discussed above, but it's possible.

Comment: no problem, please vote up the answer before setting it as answer ;-)

Comment: Stanley doesn't have reputation to vote up. So I'm giving you up vote. It is possible to get those information from ObjectContext but it is much harder.